# How to check for no longer supported installed packages on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, repository

Recently `linux-grsec` became unsupported and was removed from the Arch Linux repositories, however I was unaware of this at the time and went for a little bit with an unsupported kernel on my system which is obviously a security risk to have such a core package not be supported any more.

But now I am concerned that there may be more packages like this that have been removed from the repositories and their support on my system ended which I am simply unaware of. So as `pacman` does not appear to notify me about such packages installed on my system. I was wondering if there is a way to check if all currently installed packages are still available in the repositories and thus are still supported?

Obviously other than checking everything manually which would take ages.

Comment: `pacman -Qm`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the installed packages in the system with `pacman -Qq` and you can get all the packages in sync database with `pacman -Slq`. You then need to do a diff on the lists

```
comm -23 <(pacman -Qq | sort) <(pacman -Slq | sort)
```

You can also use `pacman -Qm` which only returns packages not in the sync database.